# How to implement ISRs and main() synchronization?

Tags: arm, microcontroller, interrupt, iar

I'm a beginner in ARM microcontroller programming and have the following problem to be solved.

1. There are two ISRs in the program: **ISR_Timer** and **ISR_Buffer**. ISR_Timer is executed each 5 minutes. ISR_Buffer is executed each time external device buffer should be filled (several times in a second). External device buffer is a small one.
2. **ISR_Buffer** takes data to fill buffer from external SRAM. There are two big buffers in SRAM. First is currently used, second is used for recalculation. Then they are swapped.
3. **ISR_Timer** sets the flag that indicates the **main()** to recalculate the second buffer in external SRAM. After that ISR_Buffer uses that buffer. The first one is used for next recalculation. Recalculation takes about 1 minute.

The problem is that both main() and ISR_Buffer access external SRAM and those accesses **are not atomic**. main() function writes data to SRAM during buffer recalculation. ISR_Buffers reads data to fill small device buffer. How to solve this issue?

**IDE**: IAR. **Chip**: AT91SAM7.

Comment: is this homework?  please tag as homework if it is.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand right, you can use [cyclic buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer). Being implemented right, it will guarantee atomic write and read.

Or, you can mask interrupts in `main()` during buffer manipulation to ensure that ISR has no access to data. But those manipulations must be fast, else your external device will get buffer underflow.